# How is possible to access to the logged out user name in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security4

We use Spring Security 4.0.x and I need to find the way to access the logged out user name.
I have configured `LogoutSuccessHandler`:

```xml
<logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
```

I see the `authentication` object in the method signature:

```java
onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
```

Unfortunately, the `authentication` object is empty.
I see that the `LogoutHandler` (`SecurityContextLogoutHandler`) clears the authentication before `logoutSuccessHandler` but I can not find the way how to configure `LogoutHandler` via `<logout ..` configuration.

How is possible to access to the logged out user name in Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (requiresLogout(request, response)) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Logging out user '" + auth
                        + "' and transferring to logout destination");
            }

            this.handler.logout(request, response, auth);

            logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, auth);

            return;
        }
```

As you can see, the filter has got the `Authentication`, So even the `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` clears the `Authentication` in `SecurityContextHolder`, the `auth` still holds the `Authentication`, Do you have any other code that clear `Authentication` before `LogoutFilter` ?

Comment: I have debugged `LogoutFilter` but I see the the authentication is already `null`. The only code  that call to `SecurityContextHolder#clearContext` is `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` and `FilterChainProxy`. 

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you find any code that about `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null or null object)` ?

Comment: I have found code that clean session before spring security.
Thank you for your help!